# Dolphin file manager stops working after mounted samba server was turned off (unexpected action?)

Tags: 12.04, kubuntu, samba, dolphin

I had mounted my samba share by editing file /etc/fstab
It works, I can use resources on remote system as well as on my hdd. However, if I turn off my samba server, dolphin (as I noticed) stops working. It just not responding to my queries. When I launching a new Dolphin application - the same thing. Is this dolphin's issue or fs mounting or what?

Answer (score 1):

This avoids more heavy handed solutions, like rebooting.

1. Edit `/etc/fstab` to make sure that the line for that mount has either the option `users` set or `user=<your user name>`. This way you are able to unmount the share without `sudo`.
2. Create a desktop shell script with command:

   ```
   umount /path/to/mountpoint/of/sambaShare
   ```
3. Optional: place the script where you can easily call it.

Now when the samba share server is off and the share is still mounted just call this script.

Now Dolphin should gracefully close. If not, terminate it because it freezed (trying to get information from samba server and re-mounting it again if fail).

This works for me.

References:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fstab